# Effect of interruption of photoperiod in a short day plant

Tags: photoperiod

When a short day plant is exposed to its critical period of darkness it flowers. But when it is exposed to a small period of red light which exceeds the critical period it doesn't flower.

But when it is exposed to small and equal amounts of red light and far red light it flowers even though it exceeds the critical period of light.

How is this possible?

Comment: can you add the source of this info? more importantly, is it homework?

Comment: I read it in a magazine

Comment: which plant species?

Comment: It is not mentioned in it...